# Python requests not working or hanging when trying to access site

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm having a weird issue recently with python (3.9) requests when accessing the NASDAQ stock screener. I want to get the list of companies on the NASDAQ, NYSE, and AMEX. There is a link for each exchange where the request returns a json that has all the information I want. The following is the link for the NYSE for example: https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&exchange=NYSE&download=true

If I just use the above link in a browser, it loads the json file and all the information just fine. My issue is that whenever I try to use requests to load the json file, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't return any response or response code...it just seems to hang for an indefinite amount of time.

Even with something as simple as the following, nothing happens for me:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&exchange=NYSE&download=true")
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on? I didn't find any cookies being passed or anything like that. And before whenever there was a cookie that was required for other sites, I remember always having a failed response being returned anyways.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: To show what I mean by literally nothing happening, this is what it looks like for me when I try to run the sample code:

[Python shell running sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqGt5.png)

It just stays like that forever. No errors, doesn't exit, no response, nothing for me to use to figure out what is going on.

Comment: "nothing happens for me" doesn't describe the problem well. Can you be a bit more specific and add the traceback (if any)?

Comment: I edited my question and added an image of the code running in a shell for me. I agree with you that "nothing happens for me" isn't helpful, but that is literally the case in this situation. I don't get any sort of output or anything at all.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Edit your question and paste the code as plain text.

Comment: I'm so confused. I already had the two lines of code in question included in the code tag. The screenshot is what I get when I run those two lines of code since you didn't believe me when I said "nothing happens". I'll admit I'm not the most experienced with python, but I have no idea what else to post to help explain my situation.

Comment: Try to pass your HTTP headers: `headers = {"User-Agent":"YOUR_USER_AGENT"}`, then `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`. You can find your user agent [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending)

Comment: Thanks, submitting user-agent in the header worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try ton change your headers. Add parameter to your requests by using headers as
headers={'Referer': referlink on the website,
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/57.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.96 Safari/57.36',
}
you can see your headers by using inspect element on chrome, look the requests you've made and the headers should be in.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this:

```py
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
URL = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&exchange=NYSE&download=true"
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, timeout=5)
```

Hope this helps! xoxo